# Replacing raster values by list GEE

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, image, reclassify, replace

I have a raster that I have mapped his values. I have made a new list of values that I want to replace them. But I want the replacement to be by pixel to pixel.

Example:
original raster pixels value = [1,2,5,6]
new list = [5,6,7,8]

with `remap` function all values in the original raster will turn to 6, but I want each pixel to turn into the corresponding value.

How do I do that?

```
var raster1 = ee.Image(image)
var raster2 = ee.Image(image2)
var raster3 = ee.Image(image3)
print(raster1)

Map.addLayer(raster1,{min: 0, max: 9, palette: palette}, 'raster1');
Map.addLayer(raster2,{min: 0, max: 9, palette: palette}, 'raster2');
Map.addLayer(raster3,{min: 0, max: 9, palette: palette}, 'raster3');

// Sample all pixels in each raster within the ROI
var sampledPixels1 = raster1.sample({
  region: geometry,
  scale: 30, // Adjust the scale as needed
  numPixels: 1e9, // Set a large number to sample all pixels
  seed: 0 // Optional seed for reproducibility
});
print(sampledPixels1)

// Sample all pixels in each raster within the ROI
var sampledPixels2 = raster2.sample({
  region: geometry,
  scale: 30, // Adjust the scale as needed
  numPixels: 1e9, // Set a large number to sample all pixels
  seed: 0 // Optional seed for reproducibility
});

var sampledPixels3 = raster3.sample({
  region: geometry,
  scale: 30, // Adjust the scale as needed
  numPixels: 1e9, // Set a large number to sample all pixels
  seed: 0 // Optional seed for reproducibility
});

var pixelValuesArray1 = sampledPixels1.aggregate_array('b1'); // Replace 'band_name_1' with the actual band name
var pixelValuesArray2 = sampledPixels2.aggregate_array('b1');

// Map the function over the image
var updatedImage = raster1.remap(ee.List(pixelValuesArray1), ee.List(pixelValuesArray3), null, 'b1');

// Visualize or export the updated image
Map.addLayer(updatedImage, {min: 0, max: 9, palette: palette}, 'updatedImage');
```